# Where is the Session stored?

Tags: c#, asp.net, session

I ask to my friend, where is session stored? At Server or Browser?
He said, at the server.
Then I said "I think things saved at server called cache".

Then, I go to google search reading article, but I found no specific correct answer, at MSDN too, no specific answer.

Comment: In Server memory, it exists for every user as opposed to the cache.

Comment: I believe that this question could be solver reading the doc.... MSDN has good articles about session state and available storages...

Answer (score 3):

Usually it is saved in the server's memory, but you can also have a database backed cache. It is **never** cached on the client, since it can contain information that shouldn't be available to the user, like the password to your database.

The full list of places where you can save the session state can be found [on MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178586%28v=vs.140%29.aspx):

> - **InProc** mode, which stores session state in memory on the Web server. This is the default.
> - **StateServer** mode, which stores session state in a separate process called the ASP.NET state service. This ensures that session state is preserved if the Web application is restarted and also makes session state available to multiple Web servers in a Web farm.
> - **SQLServer** mode stores session state in a SQL Server database. This ensures that session state is preserved if the Web application is restarted and also makes session state available to multiple Web servers in a Web farm.
> - **Custom** mode, which enables you to specify a custom storage provider.
> - **Off** mode, which disables session state.

Answer (score 2):

Session itself is stored on the server side.Each browser accessing the server will get from the server unique Session ID. This Session ID browser sends to each page requested to the same server.
[Session](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Session_%28computer_science%29)

So on client (browser) side, only Session ID is stored in the browser [cookie.](http://www.allaboutcookies.org/cookies/)

(this is default behavior, when session cookies are enabled in the browser settings... there is also a technique called "URL rewriting" to embed Session ID as URL query parameter, each time the server is called, enabling the application to work even if browser session cookies are disabled)

For more information go through this http://ejvyas.blogspot.in/2010/02/where-is-stored-is-it-in-browser-or-at.html

Answer (score 0):

Quick answer: on both sides.

Previously, the session was stored on a **server side**. This approach implies that you have to go to a server side each time you create or validate session. The session also have to be replicated for all the web-servers. These things can sufficiently harm the performance.

The another one oldschool way to store the session data as a cookie (as it is mentioned in answers). The obvious flow is that cookies has 4kb limit.

In order to overcome it, the World Wide Web Consortium defined the **client side** [sessionStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/sessionStorage), that can be instantly added or validated and does not demand to replicate the data between web-servers.

It can be seen in browser's *Dev Tools / Application* tab. For example, this is how the session for my Facebook page looks like:

[image]

Comment: I meant client side, of course. Updated the answer. Thanks!