# C# Session Variable works only in method

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, session, session-variables

I am creating Session Variable in my ActionResult method and it works fine within this method but whenever I make a call from other method in the same Controller I get Null Reference. I read a lot of questions here and nothing really helped me. No idea what could cause this issue. If You would have any ideas on that I would be really thankful for answer.

Might help:

- The retrieve is happening on Button Click from user. But I don't think it changes anything.
- It also won't work in another method that is not called on button click.
- Method in which I retrieve it is a void method.
- It is not a timeout issue for sure. I added timeout before and did not help.

In this specific example I am using List object, but it goes the same way with any other object I will assign to Session.

Declaration:

```
  List<Thread> tList = Session["tList"] as List<Thread>;
        if (tList == null)
        {
            tList = new List<Thread>();
            Session["tList"] = tList;
        }
```

Fail Retrive in other method:

```
 var t = new Thread(() =>
        {
            foreach (var item in Session["tList"] as List<Thread>)
            {
                try
                {
                    item.Abort();
                }
                catch (Exception)
                {
                }
            }
        });
```

web.config(The whole system.web section since maye there is something else blocking it. No idea):

```
<authentication mode="Forms">
  <forms cookieless="UseCookies" loginUrl="~/user/login" slidingExpiration="true"></forms>
</authentication>
<compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5" />
<httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5" />
<httpModules></httpModules>
<sessionState cookieless="true" regenerateExpiredSessionId="true" />
```

Comment: Where is your session state being stored? Are you using a web garden or web farm (you may need to google those terms if you haven't heard of them before)?

Comment: I am using web garden. I am kind of new to asp.net and sessions and I am not even sure where are they stored as for now..

Comment: You're trying to get a session value from inside another thread, that's a bad idea and won't work without some additional hacking. Why are you running that code in a thread anyway?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30320693/where-is-the-session-stored - session state is, by default, in proc. This doesn't play well with a web garden since the multiple instances on the machine have different session state being stored. Writes to one won't be written to the other. You likely want to use `SQLServer` mode - https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178586%28v=vs.140%29.aspx .

Comment: Alright I am really dumb here. It actually appears that I moved my retrieve over starting new Thread and I don`t have nulls anymore. Should have figured it out without asking here for no reason. Thanks for Your help guys.